# How to manage loot when doing missions in fleet?

Tags: eve-online

I started doing L4 missions yesterday with a friend of mine.

We were in a fleet and thus, ISKs, loyalty points and faction standings were correctly split between the two of us, but we didn't find a proper way to manage looting and salvaging during the missions.

We both have our own corporation, which removes the possibility of having a corp hangar where we could drop all loots and refine / sell from this hangar.

We ended having one of us collect all the loot and salvage, then split the loot between us.
However, this process takes some time, and is not that simple (loot must be kept in a station where it will not be confused with the player's assets).

How do you manage the loot and salvage during fleet missions ?

Comment: How big is your corporation and how much people come into said missions?

Comment: We both are alone in our corps, made them to avoid having taxes to pay. We do missions together without any other player.

Comment: So there are 2 of you and you are both in a different corporation? What I would do then is play through the mission, but don't hand it in to the agent.Then both come back with a salvage ship and salvage all you can. Get back to the station and salvage everything. Then split the loot.

Comment: That's pretty much what we are doing now, but splitting the loot manually is kinda boring, which is why I was looking for a better solution.

Comment: Don't really think there is a better solution. Remeber, EVE is not a fast-paced game, but a game you gotta make time for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my corporation, we do missions and somebody loots everything. Then we see if somebody needs anything in particular and the rest gets salvaged. We then either split the salvage, or we give our salvage to our CEO who, in turn, gives us free ships.

This is something you have to make out with your corporation. If they are happy with your system, keep it. If you notice they are not happy with it, ask them what they would change.

Comment: Yeah, this seems a good solution for a corp, but as said in the question, we are in two differents corps.

Comment: why don't the 2 of you get in the same corp, the taxes you have to pay are made by the CEO, if the CEO makes the taxes = 0% then there's no problem.

Comment: That's one solution we were considering. We may merge our corps in one to use corp hangars.